# Why is Automatic Updates setting on Windows Server 2003 resetting itself?

Tags: windows-server-2003, automatic-update

I've recently noticed that one of the servers I manage is resetting the "Automatic Updates" setting. I'm not sure how frequently or when this is occurring, but I log in to the server about every other day via Remote Desktop Connection using the same Administrator account, and every time I check the setting it's been changed from "Download Only" to "Never Check for Updates". Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RSOP.msc` or `GPResult` to figure out if any policies regarding Windows Update are being applied to the computer.

For more info on the policy settings check out this MS article:

[How to configure automatic updates by using Group Policy or registry settings](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328010)

Perhaps also see:

[How to Use the Group Policy Results (GPResult.exe) Command Line Tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb456989.aspx)